# Push the updated master branch to remote repository which in in same project folder and configured in local git repo

Tags: javascript, git, git-remote

I have a project in below structure

[image]

[image]

My local git repository is array_code .In array_code folder I have my latest code in codemaster branch.
The remote repository has been preconfigured in to my local git repository.You can see in second image project folder.

Now how can i push the updated codemaster branch in to remote repository.

Can you please help with the command which I could figure as both are in same project folder

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your [Windows Explorer show the hidden files](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/): you will see the hidden `.git` which show which parent folder is a git repository, and which is not.

Second, when you have a repo in folder A, and updated sources in an unrelated folder B, you can do

```
cd A
git --work-tree=..\path\to\B add .
git commit -m "Import sources from B"
git push
```